# Insert Examples of FusionTables 2.0 in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I keep trying to do an INSERT SQL statement on my Fusion Table but i always get a code 400 error that says my parse query was bad. I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Could someone help?

I'm just trying to simply perform an INSERT on my table using this:

```
function test() {
  runQuery("1M1NEMsUsTEoFol3t9hj6qdWwypo2eilm-naf-AC3");
  var tableId = "1M1NEMsUsTEoFol3t9hj6qdWwypo2eilm-naf-AC3";
  var sql = "INSERT INTO 1M1NEMsUsTEoFol3t9hj6qdWwypo2eilm-naf-AC3 (Email) VALUES (\"testEmail@test.com\");";
  var query = FusionTables.Query.sql(sql);
  Logger.log(query.rows);
}
```

Here's my Error: 
Invalid query: Parse error near 'testEmail' (line 1, position 71). (line 5, file "Code")

Additionally Here's the Code 400 response I receive:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "fusiontables",
    "reason": "badQueryCouldNotParse",
    "message": "Invalid query: Parse error near 'Email' (line 1, position 71).",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid query: Parse error near 'Email' (line 1, position 71)."
 }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on Fusion Tables v2.0 API as well or examples how to use it. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or help guide me in how to do this?

Comment: I'm not an app script expert but did you check if your SQL query statement format is absolutely correct?

Comment: Figured out! Rod McChesney was right and I needed single quotes if I wanted to signify VALUES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values must be in single quotes. You can see the full syntax in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#insertRow).